# Can the padding/margin on radio buttons in IE6/IE7 be reduced to 0-1px?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, padding

In Firefox and IE8 this isn't a problem, but in IE6, and IE7 I can't seem to reduce the padding/margin on radio buttons to anything reasonable (e.g. 0px or 1px).

In the included images, you can see that the red background is huge on IE6/IE7 (even with CSS padding and margin both set to 0px) yet in Firefox/IE8 it is fine.

The reason of course is that the tree I'm rendering looks horrible with the gaps in IE6/IE7.

## IE6/IE7

[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/9985/ie7l.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/9985/ie7l.png)

## Firefox/IE8

[alt text http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/3411/ie8k.png](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/3411/ie8k.png)

Notes: the page runs in standards mode, and the red is just for illustration.

## Some sample code (for those that want to hack at it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>IE Radio button padding hell</title>
<style>
  input{
    background-color:red;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="asdf">
    <input type="radio" name="sdfgsd" value=""/>asdf<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sdfgsd" value=""/>asdf<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sdfgsd" value=""/>asdf<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sdfgsd" value=""/>asdf<br/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW, you can replace `0px` with just `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use height to solve this problem.

I am using this on class on input:

```
.radiobtn
{
border:0px;
height:14px;
}
```

on:

```
<input type="radio" class="radiobtn" name="radio"  value=""/> Yes
```

It will work fine in I.E 6.0/7.

Comment: This improved things significantly. I still get a 1px margin between vertical rows that I don't want but its much less noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and was able to fix it by floating the input element. That eliminates the small vertical 'margin' in IE6/IE7.

Comment: can you provide css snippet?

Comment: This was the missing piece of the puzzle for me. Applying width/height/overflow was close but not enough. Applying float finally got rid of the last vestige of margin.

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:visible` as well as height and width to get rid of all padding/margin in IE6/7

Answer (score 0):

> The reason of course is that the tree I'm rendering looks horrible with the gaps in IE6/IE7.

I'm guessing you're using an image file to render the dots and plusses ... maybe, to avoid those gaps when the lines are taller, you could use a taller image.

Comment: True enough... I just hate having to make extra modifications just to get it to work in IE6/IE7 :-(

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code I think your running into this "IE inherited margin bug: form elements and hasLayout"

Positioniseverything.net has a good write up on it: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/inherited_margin.html

Cheers